# Populate value for data frame row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Background**

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
product_name    price
Women's pant    20.00
Men's Shirt     30.00
Women's Dress   40.00
Blue Shirt      30.00
...
```

I am looking to create a new column called

> gender

which will contain the values Women,Men, or Unisex based in the string in the product_name

The desired result would look like this:

```
product_name    price   gender
Women's pant    20.00   women
Men's Shirt     30.00   men
Women's Dress   40.00   women
Blue Shirt      30.00   unisex
```

**My Approach**

I figured that first I should create a new column with a blank value for each row. Then I should loop through each row in the dataframe and check on the string df[product_name] to see if its a mens, womens, or unisex and fill out the respective gender row value.

Here is my code:

```
df['gender'] = ""
for product_name in df['product_name']:
    if 'women' in product_name.lower():
        df['gender'] = 'women'
    elif 'men' in product_name.lower():
        df['gender'] = 'men'
    else:
        df['gender'] = 'unisex'
```

However, I get the following result:

```
product_name    price   gender
Women's pant    20.00   men
Men's Shirt     30.00   men
Women's Dress   40.00   men
Blue Shirt      30.00   men
```

I would really appreciate some help here as I am new to python and pandas library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension with `if/else` to get your output:

```
df['gender'] = ['women' if 'women' in word 
                else "men" if "men" in word
                else "unisex" 
                for word in df.product_name.str.lower()]

df

   product_name    price    gender
0   Women's pant    20.0    women
1   Men's Shirt     30.0    men
2   Women's Dress   40.0    women
3   Blue Shirt      30.0    unisex
```

Alternatively, you could use [numpy select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to achieve the same results:

```
cond1 = df.product_name.str.lower().str.contains("women")
cond2 = df.product_name.str.lower().str.contains("men")
condlist = [cond1, cond2]
choicelist = ["women", "men"]
df["gender"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default="unisex")
```

Usually, for strings, python's iteration is much faster; you have to test that though.

Comment: Your answer is neat and just wondering, what if i had multiple strings i am using to label. For instance 'women','tight' if any of these are there in the product name then name it as female. Would i just store them in a list  or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Thanks @Sluna. You may have to adapt it. possibly ``startswith`` and a tuple of the various words, if it is based on the start of the words. Also a regex could help to search for multiple words. Again, it depends on the question format. You could ask a new question with the new options and I'll help out however I can

Answer (score 2):

Try turning your `for` statement into a function and using `apply`. So something like -

```
def label_gender(product_name):
    '''product_name is a str'''
    if 'women' in product_name.lower():
        return 'women'
    elif 'men' in product_name.lower():
        return 'men'
    else:
        return 'unisex'

df['gender'] = df.apply(lambda x: label_gender(x['product_name']),axis=1)
```

A good breakdown of using apply/lambda can be found here: https://towardsdatascience.com/apply-and-lambda-usage-in-pandas-b13a1ea037f7

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) + [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html),

```
import numpy as np

df['gender'] = (
    np.where(df.product_name.str.contains("women", case=False), 'women',
             np.where(df.product_name.str.contains("men", case=False), "men", 'unisex'))
)
```

---

```
    product_name  price  gender
0   Women's pant   20.0   women
1    Men's Shirt   30.0     men
2  Women's Dress   40.0   women
3     Blue Shirt   30.0  unisex
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where` `.str.contains` and `regex first` word` in phrase. So that;

```
#np.where(if product_name has WomenORMen, 1st Word in Phrase, otherwise;unisex)



 df['Gender']=np.where(df.product_name.str.contains('Women|Men')\
                      ,df.product_name.str.split('(^[\w]+)').str[1],'Unisex')


 
    product_name  price  gender
0   Women's pant   20.0   Women
1    Men's Shirt   30.0     Men
2  Women's Dress  640.0   Women
3    Blue Shirt    30.0  Unisex
```